# ASP.NET Web api 2- delete from array

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, web, controller

I'm building my first application with ASP.NET Web api 2, just educational purpose.I want to store data in Array ( I know, would be better in DB).
I wrote few get methods and they work fine, but I don't know why DELETE is not working like I would expect.

I would like to delete from array a Car with provided id. After running action it shows me that the Car with specific id was deleted, but when I am running action that is showing all cars in array seems like the cars is still there.

Please find a code for controller below. Anyone knows what would be the reason?

```
using System; 
using Cars.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace Cars.Controllers
{
    public class carsController : ApiController
    {
        List<Car> cars = new List<Car>(new Car[]
        {
            new Car { Id = 1, Name = "Opel", Price = 49999.9 },
            new Car { Id = 2, Name = "Fiat",  Price = 30000.0 },
            new Car { Id = 3, Name = "BMW",  Price = 100500.9 }
        });

        public HttpResponseMessage GetAllCars()
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, cars);
        }


        [HttpDelete]
        [Route("api/cars/deletecar/{id}")]
        public IHttpActionResult DeleteCar(int id)
        {
           var car = cars.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);
            if(car!=null)
            {
                for(int i=0;i<=cars.Count;i++)
                {
                    if (cars[i].Id==id)
                    {
                        cars.RemoveAt(i);

                       return Ok(cars );
                    }
                }

            }
            return NotFound();
        }
    }
```

Comment: after implementing the programtreasures's logic use `cars.Remove(car)` after getting the `car` object instead of looping through the `cars list`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your `cars` list instance creates for each request,

You should make it static property and try it

```
     static List<Car> cars = new List<Car>(new Car[]
    {
        new Car { Id = 1, Name = "Opel", Price = 49999.9 },
        new Car { Id = 2, Name = "Fiat",  Price = 30000.0 },
        new Car { Id = 3, Name = "BMW",  Price = 100500.9 }
    });
```

Answer (score -3):

The change was not assigned to the initial variable.

```
if (cars[i].Id==id)
{
    cars = cars.RemoveAt(i);

    return Ok(cars);
}
```

Comment: Cars list instance creates for each request.

Comment: more then that `RemoveAt` method of List has **void** return type, so this code will not ever compile

Comment: Ah of course, sorry was thinking of RemoveRange and those types of functions which return a copy of the modified list but do not change the object itself.